# move assignment from newly constructed object to *this in a member function

Tags: c++

Implementing a `reset()` method, which uses *some* of the members from `this` to construct a new object and then *move-assign* that object to `*this`.

Questions:

1. Does this cause any problems? UB or otherwise? (seems fine to me?)
2. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Destructor and move-assignment operator only implemented to prove what is happening/ The real class has neither. "Rule of 5" not followed, as not needed here.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

struct Thing { // NOLINT Rule of 5 not followed, because debug only
public:
  std::size_t      size;
  std::vector<int> v;

  explicit Thing(std::size_t size_) : size(size_), v(size_) {
    std::cerr << "Thing constructor\n";
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
  }

  ~Thing() { std::cerr << "Thing destructor\n"; } // purely for debugging

  Thing& operator=(Thing&& other) noexcept {  // purely for debugging
    std::cerr << "Thing Move Assignment operator\n";
    size = other.size;
    v    = std::move(other.v);
    return *this;
  }

  void shuffle() {
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{1}); // NOLINT fixed seed
  }
  void reset() {
    // move assignment operator from a newly constructed object. Constructor uses SOME of the
    // member variables of *this
    *this = Thing(size);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Thing& t) {
    os << "[";
    const char* delim = "";
    for (const auto& e: t.v) {
      os << delim << e;
      delim = ",";
    }
    return os << "]";
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cerr << "Before inital construction\n";
  auto t = Thing(10);
  std::cout << t << "\n";
  t.shuffle(); // somehow modify the object
  std::cerr << "Before reset\n";
  std::cout << t << "\n";
  t.reset(); // reset using
  std::cerr << "after reset\n";
  std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Before inital construction
Thing constructor
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Before reset
[10,1,3,6,8,5,7,4,2,9]
Thing constructor
Thing Move Assignment operator
Thing destructor
after reset
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Thing destructor
```

Comment: So you follow the "rule of zero", that's the ideal.

Comment: Yes the Special member functions above are not there in our code. But that's not really the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does this cause any problems? UB or otherwise? (seems fine to me?)

As long as the move assignment and the constructor are implemented in such a way that it does what you want, then I don't see a problem.

> 2. Is there a more idiomatic way?

I would invert the direction of re-use.

```
explicit Thing(std::size_t size_) : size(size_), v(size_) {
    reset();
}

void reset() {
    v.resize(size_);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
}
```

If `size` is supposed to always match the size of the vector, then I would recommend removing the member since the size is already stored inside the vector. This has a caveat that in such case `reset` won't be able to restore a moved-from thing to its earlier size. But that's typically reasonable limitation.

Comment: Fair point about size. The real class is more complex and I wanted to demonstrate that there is a second member which is used in the construction of a non-trivial type. In the real code the `size` is actually modified by the calling code, and that change only takes affect after reset. Before `reset()` the internals of the class use the equivalent of `v.size()`.

Comment: Your point about "inverting direction of use" is also fair. However, we can't do that, because the non-trivial member (represented by the vector here) cannot be easily resized. It needs to be sized correctly  during construction. (it's a 2D-Matrix class).